# How to get data from multiple Nested FXMLs And call methods on their controllers

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

Here's what my project looks like:

`Main.FXML`

- AnchorPane

  - VBox   [Egg Container] id="_eggContainer"
  - Button [Add Egg] --> Adds an eggview to _eggContainer
  - Button [Print Eggs] --> prints all eggs' properites
  - Button [Break Eggs] --> Calls break method on each egg

`EggView.FXML`

- HBox

  - Label: [Egg ID] Should be incremented each time an eggView is instantiated
  - TextField: [Egg Color]

`MainController.java`

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {   

    /***CONTROLS***/
    @FXML private VBox   _eggsContainer;
    @FXML private Button _btnAddEgg;
    @FXML private Button _btnPrintEggs;
    @FXML private Button _btnBreakEggs;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        _btnAddEgg.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            doAddEgg();
        });
        _btnPrintEggs.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            doPrintAllEggs();
        });
        _btnBreakEggs.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            doBreakAllEggs();
        });
    }

    // Add an egg to _eggsContainer
    private void doAddEgg() {
        HBox eggControl = null;
        try {
            eggControl = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("EggView.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        _eggsContainer.getChildren().add(eggControl);
    }

    private void doPrintAllEggs() {
        // prints ID and Color of each egg in _eggsContainer
    }

    private void doBreakAllEggs() {
        // call the break method in EggController controller on each egg
    }
}
```

`EggController.java`

```
public class EggController {

    /***CONTROLS***/
    @FXML private Label _eggID;
    @FXML private TextField _eggColor;

    public void doBreakEgg() {
        // TODO: Break Egg
    }

    /****************************************************************
     **********                  ACCESSORS               ************
     ****************************************************************/
    public String getEggID() {
        return _eggID.getText();
    }

    public String setEggID(String id) {
        return _eggID.setText(id);
    }

    public String getEggColor() {
        return _eggColor.getText();
    }
```

}

Now how can i access each eggs data and methods from my main controller? Without having to give each egg an ID and reference it in MainController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the controllers from the `FXMLLoader`s when you load `EggView.fxml`, and put them in a list. (As an aside, don't use mouse listeners to handle button actions.)

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {   

    /***CONTROLS***/
    @FXML private VBox   _eggsContainer;
    @FXML private Button _btnAddEgg;
    @FXML private Button _btnPrintEggs;
    @FXML private Button _btnBreakEggs;

    private final List<EggController> eggs = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        _btnAddEgg.setOnAction(e -> {
            doAddEgg();
        });
        _btnPrintEggs.setOnAction(e -> {
            doPrintAllEggs();
        });
        _btnBreakEggs.setOnAction(e -> {
            doBreakAllEggs();
        });
    }

    // Add an egg to _eggsContainer
    private void doAddEgg() {
        HBox eggControl = null;
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("EggView.fxml"));
            eggControl = loader.load();
            EggController controller = loader.getController();
            eggs.add(controller);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        _eggsContainer.getChildren().add(eggControl);
    }

    private void doPrintAllEggs() {
        // prints ID and Color of each egg in _eggsContainer
        for (EggController controller : eggs) {
            System.out.println(controller.getEggId() + " : " + controller.getEggColor());
        }
    }

    private void doBreakAllEggs() {
        eggs.forEach(EggController::doBreakEgg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you james! Didn't know you could get a reference of the controller from the FXMLLoader! 
Thanks for the tip also, but i'm curious as to why setOnAction is better.

Comment: @JawnyThompson Because the mouse listener won't be invoked if the user uses the keyboard to activate the button... (Also, the interaction between the mouse and a button is more complex than you think anyway. E.g. should the button be considered pressed if the user presses the mouse button, moves off the button with the mouse button still down, then releases? Etc etc.)

Comment: Ohh wow, thanks lol. i always had this problem where i had to do it like this
`handleButton(new MouseEvent(100 THOUSAND PARAMETERS));`